# Changing the order items are retrieved from the DB in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp

I've made a forum using CakePHP while following a tutorial and would like to expand it.

Currently, in a post it allows me to comment, but they are displayed as newest -> oldest, so it doesn't make as much sense and I would like to reverse this.

This is the current association I have, I'm pretty new to PHP/Cake so I'm not sure where to go from here, any help is very appreciated!

```
public $hasMany = array(
        'Post' => array(
            'className' => 'Post',
            'foreignKey' => 'forum_id',
            'dependent' => false,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'exclusive' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'counterQuery' => ''
        )
```

For those asking this is the function in my controller:

```
public function add($topicId=null) {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->request->data['Post']['user_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');

            if ($this->Post->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Post has been created'));
                $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'topics','action'=>'view',$this->request->data['Post']['topic_id']));
            }

        } else {
            if (!$this->Post->Topic->exists($topicId)) {
                throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid topic'));
            }

            $this->Post->Topic->recursive = -1;
            $topic = $this->Post->Topic->read(null,$topicId);

            $this->Post->Forum->recursive = -1;
            $forum = $this->Post->Forum->read(null,$topic['Topic']['forum_id']);

            $this->set('topic',$topic);
            $this->set('forum',$forum);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Spend a little time in the [docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html) and you'll find the answers.

Comment: You should include the function of that controller which displaying comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'Post' => array(
        'className' => 'Post',
        'foreignKey' => 'forum_id',
        'dependent' => false,
        'order' => 'Post.created ASC' //order the Posts in ascending order based on whe they were created
    )
```

Assuming you have a created column in your database table.

Edit:
You can find more info in the CakePHP documentation http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html

Comment: I do have a column for posts, but this does not quite work for me. Is there a way i could call it numerically by post id?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure if I understand you comment. Is the association you posted currently working, but your results are in the wrong order?

Comment: Yes, the association I have has it so it reads newest posts first and scrolls down to oldest, I would like this reversed.
To clarify, I have two things `topics` and `posts` on a forum, `topics` would be like a thread, which those display newest to oldest, which is fine. but `posts` would be like `replies` to a topic, which i would like displaying oldest to newest so you can read the whole thread by just scrolling down.

Comment: Okay, sorry, my code was still ordering newest to oldest (oops), have flipped it now and added further clarification.

Comment: Still not ordering correctly, but I messed around trying to get it with `'order' => 'Post.id ASC'` but still nothing. I did just notice that all the post dates are the same, so maybe that is confused? But they still order the same without the added logic.. hmm Is there anything I can do with the `foreignKey` since all the `forum_id`s are the same?

Comment: Can you post the contents of the table and model, so I can see what data we're working with?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81008/discussion-between-user4875251-and-gopalmer).

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using `read()`, it is better to use `find('first')`. So you could rewrite your queries like:-

```
$this->Post->Topic->find('first', array(
    'contain' => array(
        'Post' => array(
            'order' => array(
                'Post.created' => 'asc',
                'Post.id' => 'asc'
            )
        )
    )
));
```

Passing an array instead of a string for `order` allows you to sort by multiple conditions. The above example would create the following `ORDER` SQL:-

```
ORDER BY Post.created ASC, Post.id ASC
```

You can also define a default ordering on the model itself which can be very useful:-

```
class Post extends AppModel {

    public $order = array('Post.created' => 'asc', 'Post.id' => 'asc');

}
```

Comment: Nothing changed, hmm I wonder if there is something stopping all of these changes..

Comment: What is the SQL query being generated for this find?

Comment: SELECT `Post`.`id`, `Post`.`topic_id`, `Post`.`forum_id`, `Post`.`created`, `Post`.`modified`, `Post`.`content`, `Post`.`user_id` FROM `Forum`.`posts` AS `Post` WHERE `Post`.`forum_id` = (1) ORDER BY `Post`.`created` DESC

Comment: That SQL looks correct to me. Cake is correctly applying the ordering. Looks like the issue might be with your data in the database. Are all the `created` dates the same? This data should be being auto created when Cake first adds a record to the posts table. Is it the correct `DATETIME` format in the database?

Comment: No, all of my dates from today are the same, down to the minute in the Time.

Dates are different in DB, but not on my localhost site

Comment: @user4875251 if the dates are all the same then you won't see any change in the ordering if you order by that date. Try ordering by both `created` and `id` columns as shown in my answer and you should see the correct ordering as it will first order by `created` (to no effect if they are all the same) and then on `id`. It might be a good idea to update your local database to better reflect the real data.